# why do i get this Error: ng:areq Bad Argument

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i couldn't find the error  i even searched but no result please help me here is my code 
 index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="app">


   <div ng-view></div>

    
  <script src="controller.js"></script>  
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"> </script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-route.min.js"> </script>

   
   
    
    
</body>
</html>
```

login.html

```html
<div ng-controller="loginCtrl">
<form action="/" id="myLogin">
Username:<input type="text" name="username" id="username" ng-model="username">
Pasword:<input type="password" name="password" id="password" ng-model="password">
    <button ng-click="submit()">Login</button>
</form>
</div>
```

controller.js

```js
var application=angular.module('app',['ngRoute']);
application.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
    .when('/',{
        templateUrl:'login.html'
    })
    .when('/Dashboard',{
          templateUrl:'dashboard.html'
          })
    .otherwise({
        template:'404 not found'
    });
     });
application.controller('loginCtrl',function($scope,$location){
        $scope.submit=function(){
        var uname=$scope.username;
        var password=$scope.password;
        if($scope.username =='admin' && $scope.password=='admin'){
            $location.path('/Dashboard');
        }
    };
});
```

> i couldn't find where is the error
>   and when i try it i get this error 
>   https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ng/areq?p0=loginCtrl&p1=not%20a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have placed the `loginCtrl` at the wrong place. [Check out this plunk.](http://plnkr.co/edit/be8jfx?p=preview)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"> </script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-route.min.js"> </script>
<script src="controller.js"></script>        
</head>

<body ng-app="app"  ng-controller="loginCtrl">   

   <div ng-view></div>                        

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Plunk is working. Paste your 'dashboard.html' file also to further probe into this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Change the order of `<script>` tag to

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"> </script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-route.min.js"> </script>
<script src="controller.js"></script>
```